# Is there a way to add a space between two regions of a map using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, spatial

I'm struggling with a problem. I'd like to separate two countries by adding some space between them. The idea is, for example, to explode europe, by still showing each country but with e predefined space between each country.

I'm using R and ggplot for the project I'm working and until now I tried to look for some answer on the web but could not find anything. You can get something by changing the size but that solution will also imply a loss on the details of the map.

If you could help that would be super great!

Comment: separating a pair of countries should be doable. Use `ggplot::map_data` and change the latitudes/longitudes by a fixed amount per country. Doing this for all of Europe will be very tedious

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but you can try to scale the polygons to <100% of the originals...

```
library(sf)
library(magrittr)
```

**sample data**

```
#read shapefile with country polygons
# source: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip
map <- st_read( "./data/countries/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp" )
#filter out some relevant countries
benelux <- c("Belgium", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands")
map <- map %>% filter( NAME %in% benelux ) 

#what do we have?
ggplot() + geom_sf( data = map )
```

[image]

**code**

```
#scale the polygons to 75% of original
#extract geometry
map.sfc = st_geometry(map)
#get centroids
map.centroid = st_centroid(map.sfc)
#recalculate geometry, scale to 75%
map.scale = ( map.sfc - map.centroid ) * 0.75 + map.centroid
#replace original geoemtry by recalculated geometry. set crs back to WGS84
map.scale_sf = st_set_geometry(map, map.scale) %>% st_set_crs( 4326 )

#ewhat do we have now?
ggplot() + geom_sf( data = map.scale_sf )
```

[image]